# Sequelize 'afterValidate' hook does not change values

Tags: hook, sequelize.js

I've got a problem with the sequelize hooks. The following code does its job very well when i create a new instance. But when it comes to updating an existent database entry the values of rec.working_time and rec.break_duration are not wirtten back to the database

I can see that the hook is called by adding some console logs and the rec values change as well. But somhow there is no update on theese fields.
If i do the same with an 'beforeUpdate' everything works fine with the same code.

```
TimeRecording.hook('afterValidate', rec => {
    var moment = require('moment');
    var models = require('../models');

    let workingTime = moment(rec.time_to).diff(rec.time_from, 'minutes', null);
    let workingHours = workingTime / 60;

    return models.BreakControl.max('break_duration',
      {
        where: { working_time: { lt: workingHours } }
      })
      .then(breakControl => {
        breakControl = breakControl ? breakControl : 0;

        rec.working_time = workingTime - breakControl;
        rec.break_duration = breakControl;
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Here also a quck look on the important attributes in the model:

```
time_from: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  allowNull: false,
},
time_to: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  validate: {
    isAfter: function (value, next) {
      let self = this;
      if (self.time_from > value) {
        return next('time_to must be after time_from!');
      }
      return next();
    }
  }
},
required_time: {
  type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(4, 0)
},
working_time: {
  type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(4, 0),
  validate: {
    min: 0
  }
},
break_duration: {
  type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(4, 0)
}
```

So am i missing something, or did i fail to understand some critical concept here?

Thanks for any information on this.

Comment: I tried doing it the exact same way you are and it worked just fine. Can you reproduce this separately and put it in a gist on github?

Comment: Thank you for your time on this.
I just noticed, that i listed the 'beforeUpdate' hook in the above code.
Ofcourse it had to be 'afterValidate'. If you did it with 'afterValidate' anyway, then i have to doublecheck this.
Sadly my time is very limited right now and it might take me some days to upload a sample on gist.
But again thank you very much so far. I'll hopefully get back to this at the end of the week.